# Merging files into one folder from different level folders in terminal

Tags: mac, terminal

I have a music folder for iTunes which has a lot of other subfolders. I want to copy all the MP3 files into a single folder. How can I do it fast? Is a the a command line that I can use to do the trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ‘find’ to search `/path/to/music` for all files with names ending in ‘mp3’ and use ‘cp’ to copy them to `/path/to/newfolder`.

```
find /path/to/music -name "*.mp3" -exec cp {} /path/to/newfolder \;
```